# My Application is shutting down itself and logcat is not showing any error messages

Tags: java, android

I am using my android phone as emulator and current version of android is marshmallow. When I run an application which is having exceptions, the application in my phone is simply closing and it is even not saying application has stopped working. And android studio is not showing anything about the error occurred in application. Previously in eclipse as well as android studio it used say application has stopped working and it used to show all the error in logcat. Now I am using android studio version 2.2.3 and its so much helpless to find error present in the application. So can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Integrate with crashlytics

Comment: Try `adb logcat` from the terminal. Or download some Logcat app separately on your device. Most likely reason = out of memory force-closing your app.

Comment: can u please be more specific about the crashlytics and its fuction and procedure to integrate to android studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void handleUncaughtExceptions()
{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

try implementing this method in your main activity and calling it in onCreate() of your main activity and see if you can see the crash logs. You can also try and put a breakpoint there and try to reproduce the crash and see what's going on

Comment: Its not working,  it is saying create handleUncaughtException method

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with android studio. It was my mobile which was not giving proper reply to android studio's logcat. I used the genymotion emulator and its working fine now.