# My Android Phone is not reporting errors to Android Studio's Logcat when a application I am building crashes

Tags: android

Whenever there is presence of any error in my application my phone automatically closes the application,it doesn't even show "Your application is stopped working" pop up messages.

In  logcat there is nothing to about the crash. But when I install same application to other phones it is showing all the errors in logcat.

Can anybody tell me, is there anything to turn on or off in developer option to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Application is shutting down itself and logcat is not showing any error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377768/my-application-is-shutting-down-itself-and-logcat-is-not-showing-any-error-messa)

Comment: Please don't repost

Comment: I am new  about asking questions in stackoverflow and learning stage of android too. My previous question was slightly different then this one. Previously I was thinking that android studio's logcat has problem but it was not  and later I solved it by using another emulator. Now I know my phone has problem.So now  I am just trying to solve problem occurred in my phone.

Comment: It's essentially the same problem. The adb connection between your device and the computer isn't validated. You can run all this outside of Android Studio from the terminal to see what happens. `adb logcat`